# InputStream won't open a stream to a specified URL

Tags: java, android, url, exception, inputstream

I'm simply trying to load a URL into an InputStream but it never seems to manage.

```
private void getWebpage(String url)
{
    URL myFileUrl = null;  

    try
    {
         myFileUrl= new URL(url);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        System.out.println("Some URL Exception");
    }

    try
    {
        InputStream in = myFileUrl.openStream();
        System.out.println("Does it get here?");
        is = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        in.close();
        is.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Some IO Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Some Exception");
    }   
}
```

It never prints out "Does it get here?" to the console but it does print out Some IO Exception. There aren't the best error messages in the world I know.

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace` instead of `System.out.println` to get a more useful error message

Comment: Are you sure your app has the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ?

Comment: I have the user permission line in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Is it breaking out to one of the exceptions instead then? If it cannot open the file then it will jump down to the catch statement

EDIT: Actually are you trying to load a webpage?

Comment: Yes it is being caught by the IOException

Comment: There is something wrong with the string value you are passing to it. What is it your trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to load the contents of a webpage into a string.If the URL is incorrect then I should be able to set myFileUrl to be something like http:// www.google.com and it should then work. I tested that but it still does the same thing.

Comment: have you looked at what exception it is throwing

Comment: request time failed: java .net .SocketException Address family not supported by protocol

Answer (score 0):

In general the code is working fine.

So there must be a problem with your network connection. Do you have a direkt connection to the internet or do you have to pass a proxy?

Comment: I guess you are testing with the emulator, aren't you? In this case, you should try to recreate a new AVD. ("Have you tried to turn it off and on again?" --The IT crowd)